# Application Icon missing Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

AM using for **Eclipse** for my android programming stuff.

But after running my application into my **Samsung Galaxy Tablet** , the **icon is missing** in home or applications. But it appearing in , *`Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applications`*
.
It does bothering from last couple of days it bothering me, before that i didn't seem like that.

Comment: one more thing, remaining all applications working fine except one applicvation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by removing this line for my launcher activity :

The problem is `<data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />`

Comment: did you check @PadmaKumar answer? Did you have the <intent-filter> tag in your xml?

Comment: yes i have intent-filter tag , in that with action and category. i kept data scheme stuff to my launcher activiy, so its missing.

Comment: My  issue solved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133954/launcher-icon-missing-in-android

Answer (score 3):

you need to add below line in androidmanifest.xml file

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

android.intent.category.LAUNCHER is necessary to be shown in launcher, and android.intent.action.MAIN is responsible for being started. thats y your application icon is not displayed in the app list. but it will show in  Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applications.

Answer (score 2):

you should delete all default icons and replace them with your own in all drawable folders and restart the app. try to debug directly on your phone..

Comment: default icons in the sense, ?

Comment: default icons are the ones which come into life when you set your project. if you start your app for the first time without having your own icon, default android icon is set. and these icons are to delete, if you set your own one.. as i mentioned, they are in all drawable folders...

Answer (score 1):

You have to create different icons and add them in "res/drawable" folder.

For more detailed information, please read Google's [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing you Level-2 RAM on your device. This used to happen to me on my HTC, but that usually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Me too had similar experience when doing deeplinking and the issue was i edited already existing `<inten-filter>` tag,the correct way is add new `<intent-filter>` as shown

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!--add deeplinking info as a seperate intent-filter-->
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/qlink"
            />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->

    </intent-filter>
```

Reference :[reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611591/5706413) [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611591/5706413)