# Launcher icon missing in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

My manifest launcher activity looks like:

```
 <activity android:name=".CBMainMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

                <data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Other applications are correctly installing but why does this app not?
I can see this app in `Applications>Manage Applications` but it missing in shortcut.

Here is my full manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.check.careerbuilder"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission>


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.youtube"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" >
        <activity android:name=".CBMainMenu" android:label="CB Ambassador" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

                <data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name=".GoogleMap"></activity>


     <activity android:name=".Verify"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".VideoPush"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
      <activity android:name=".Videoclass"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>

      <activity android:name=".SocialMedia" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".PreviewActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />


        <activity android:name=".SearxhJobs"  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutUs"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Benefits"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".EndJobList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".FirstJobList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondJobList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Pleaseselect"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ThirdJobList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".FourthJobList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".JobsCities" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".JobsTypes" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".JobDescription" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>

<activity android:name="ReferAFriend" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Faq" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>

<activity android:name=".ThanksActivity1" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ThanksActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".EmailThisJob" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".MyDialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".FileManagerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ReferPopup" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Jobs" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Youtube" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Profile" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Colleagues" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ColleagueProfile" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Takephoto" ></activity>
<activity android:name=".TwitterFollowers" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".FacebookFriends" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".LinkedinFriends" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Moreoptions" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Reader" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Shareweb" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Groupon" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".DealsShow" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".LocalWeather" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

 <activity android:name="com.brightcove.android.oneplanet.Playlists"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.brightcove.android.oneplanet.Videos"
                android:label="@string/videos_activity" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.brightcove.android.oneplanet.Player"
                android:label="@string/player_activity"
                android:configChanges="orientation"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity android:theme="@style/YtdTheme" android:name="com.google.ytd.SubmitActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

        <activity android:theme="@style/YtdTheme" android:name="com.google.ytd.DetailsActivity"/>
        <activity android:theme="@style/YtdTheme" android:name="com.google.ytd.SubmitActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>      

<activity android:name="com.check.careerbuilder.SmsTo" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
 <activity android:name="com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" android:host="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   

    <activity android:name=".CustomDataActivity" android:label="Custom Data" android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.check.careerbuilder.DISPLAY_CUSTOM_DATA" />


                        <data android:scheme="notif" />

            </intent-filter>

</activity>




    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  />


   <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm" />
</manifest>
```

How to resolve this? what could the problem be?

Comment: Are you missing android:icon="@drawable/icon" under <application tag in menifest file?

Comment: no am not its android:icon="@drawable/appicon" is there..

Comment: Can you provide your full manifest file?

Comment: The problem is  <data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />
if you remove this line then it will work fine...so thats the issue..I checked this in emulator

Comment: what is issue with this tag ?

Comment: I have the same issue, if I remove the `<data android:scheme="..." android:host="..." />` then the icon appears, but the problem is, I need it to be both launchable from icon, and also respond to custom scheme intent. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is <`data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />` , you cannot logically use this tag in launcher activity, See below line , I taken from http://blog.marcingil.com/2011/03/starting-android-application-from-browser-uri/

***Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the user any activities without it set when performing an action on some data. Note that this is normal -not- set in the Intent when initiating an action — it is for use in intent filters specified in packages.***

Comment: ohhh, that is just sooo stupid, I need to be able to read an input params from a scheme in my main activity that I'm launching from the link in the email by using the android:scheme param. google just shoot themselves in the leg by contradicting themselves.

Comment: It worked for me, i had scheme="http" and scheme="https". BTW the link to that blog is broken

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477542/app-not-listed-in-launcher-due-to-data-androidscheme-http-in-androidmanif

Answer (score 4):

The solution is not given in this topic. The real solution is to use multiple intent filters and is given here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611591/1828637

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old. But, answering it for the benefit of someone who would face the same problem.
The launcher activity should have specific filter as below in order for it to show up in the apps list.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Still app icon not found for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

```
android:label="My App"
```

like this:

```
<activity android:name=".CBMainMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:label="My App" >
```

Comment: I added like android:label="CB Ambassador" , but its still missing

Answer (score -1):

For some days i have been facing the same problem, cant find my launcher icon. So here's what i did.
The launcher activity should have this(MAIN)`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"`

Also have you tried it after removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"` in your `

```
            <data android:scheme="linkedinapp" android:host="connect" />
        </intent-filter>`
```

Hope it helps.