# App installed through android studio not shown in Launcher

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

All of a sudden the app i'm working on doesn't show in the launcher. I can see it in Settings>Apps and it runs like a normal app when I start it from Android Studio.

So it sounds like I'm missing:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

in the manifest. Nope they're there. What else can cause this? Does build gradle mess with this possibly?

This is my full manifest and build gradle file. Can anyone see something I'm missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.app" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="xxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="xxxx" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:host="com.example.twitter.oauth" android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.SigninActivity"
        android:label="@string/sign_in"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.PostActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_new"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.twitter.OAuthActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_new"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.app.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.example.app.gcm.GCMIntentService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def value = 0

        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1;
        }

        def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 0
        def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def version_Code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = version_Code.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode version_Code
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild}) Alpha"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('xxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
        }
        releaseKey {
            storeFile file('xxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'com.example.app'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            runProguard false
        }
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':parallaxViewPager')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

Comment: There appears to be an error in your "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

The <manifest> tag appears to be missing - although you do show an ending </manifest> tag.  Is the tag missing or is this just a cut-and-paste error?

Comment: Its a copy/paste error. You had my hopes up there for a second! :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can actually have an intent filter with `data android:host` in the launcher activity. It just needs to be a separate filter to the one containing the launcher category. The following setup makes my activity both a launcher one and browsable in order to read input parameters:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name_full">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="www.giorgos.nl"
                  android:pathPrefix="/cv" />
            <data android:scheme="cv"
                  android:host="giorgos"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Different intent save my day. This cause for me, nothing app in home screen and the impossibility to create an icon with intent shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from this question solved it for me: [Launcher icon missing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133954/launcher-icon-missing-in-android)

Its apparently impossible to have < data android:host... in the launcher activity.

Comment: giorgos29cm's solution worked in my case, so it is now possible to contain a <data android:host... in a separate intent-filter.

Comment: I put `<data android: scheme...>` outside of the `<intent>` tags, but inside the `<activity>` tags

Comment: @just_user yes perfectly! I implemented it this morning it seems to be running without any issues.