# The app icon is missing/doesn't appear android studio

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio

I have this layout and in the manifest, I placed the line `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`, but the app icon is not shown...

**Layout's content:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".java0"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="#ffff7e00">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="theapp.application.app.theapp" >

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!--Agregado: Pantallas-->
    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".java0"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".java1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".java2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: rename your class name java0 to Java. check my update answer :)

Comment: I had the same problem n got the solution also

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133954/launcher-icon-missing-in-android

Answer (score 0):

your `manifest` structure should be like in  `Android Studio`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  package="com.org.yourpackage" >
        <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".YourStartingActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Note : for **transparent background** you should use

```
android:style/Theme.Translucent
```

and Just rename all your java class name ( start it with caps.. )

Comment: Yeah but... Now what?, I only pasted the full manifest file, the app icon is still missing.

Comment: Your application is installed in your device ?