# Application doesn't show up in Home Screen

Tags: android, xml, apk

**Problem**

> My mobile application called "Pipe" doesn't show up on Home Screen

---

**How is it before**

> Before i tried to modify `AndroidManifest.xml` it working fine before, it's on the Home Screen

---

**What i wanted**

> App to show up on Home Screen

---

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gell.browserx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true"
            android:name=".Applications"
        android:resizeableActivity="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:exported="true">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <data android:scheme="pipe" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.SettingActivity"
            android:label="Pipe Setting">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <data android:scheme="pipe-setting" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
        <activity android:name=".common.crash.CrashHandler$CrashActiviy"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".DebugActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.max_aspect"
            android:value="4.0"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass `android:scheme` inside the launcher activity `intent-filter`. You need to either remove this or pass it in a different `intent-filter`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133954/launcher-icon-missing-in-android/8134686#8134686) too.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.. I already fixed it a long time ago though, xD. After all, it's just an old question. Still, thank you.