# Trying to add Deep Linking my Android App

Tags: android, deep-linking

My app is working fine but whenever i add deep link code in my manifest my app lunching icon disappears this is my manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="gizbo.ae" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When ever i add these three line for deep linking. App icon launching icon disappears from device.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="gizbo.ae" />
```

even i removed these two lines

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```

again same problem.

i just want to make my app visible  in Google search and i am following this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Comment: Have you tried defining `data` in this way: 

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="gizbo.ae" />`

Comment: i don't have any pathPrefix.

Comment: Still same problem app icon disappears.

Comment: Is the LoginActivity activity your LAUNCHER activity.

Comment: Yes, LoginActivity activity is my LAUNCHER activity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use multiple intent-filter tags:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="gizbo.ae" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: thanks man it works...with this code my app will display in google search or i have to add some uri?

Comment: No, you should implement the App Indexing API: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another activity to use deep linking and then start your login activity and pass your data to that.

So declare the activity as below:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DeelinkActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">
            <!-- URL scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:host="gizbo.ae"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- End URL scheme -->
  </activity>
```

and then in onCreate in that activity you can call the login activity also from there you can pass your data to that activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    //put code to pass data as extras and Start your login activity here
}
```

Good luck.